# How display 2 items on Jade each looping?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Not working and have no idea

index.js

```
res.render('index', { items: doc, 
                      items2 : percentArray});
```

index.jade

```
div
    each item in items
        each item2 in items2
            p= item.title
            p= items2
```

Comment: I think you're doing it wrong. Looks like you definitely should be able to use one each instead of this bad idea

Comment: Can be might another way?

Comment: you would need to share more code to share your sample data

Comment: items contains docs from MongoDB RegularExp query. Items2 contains simple array of count match in document string. My task to make display all finded documens from each and this works. And I would be againt each title document display count match strings of this document.

Comment: what does the items2 array contain ?

Comment: Array contain the number match string in DB document

Comment: you need to provide sample data and explain you logic. You definitely have to remodel it but we need to understand it to help you